# How to use background media player in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone application for Windows 8.1. I need to use features like Motion classes, Isolated Storage etc. As these features were not supported in Windows Phone 8.1 I went for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. Now I have to use BackgroundMediaPlayer in my project and Windows.Media.Playback is not supported in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. Is there any possible way by which i can use all the basic API's like:-

-Microsoft.Devices.Sensors

-Microsoft.Xna.Framework

-System.IO.IsolatedStorage-System.Windows.Media.Imaging

and use BackgroundMediaPlayer, Motion classes?? any help will be really useful.

Thanks,

Ekta

Answer (score 7):

Playing Background audio differs in [Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx) and [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx) ([Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx)). You were trying to use [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.aspx) which:

> Minimum supported phone  Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

is only for runtime.

As for working with [BackgroundAudioPlayer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer(v=vs.105).aspx) in Silverlight 8.1, there is a problem - it won't work. This is a [limitation in Silverlight 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642084(v=vs.105).aspx):

> The AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent classes, which supported background audio playback for Windows Phone 8 apps, are not supported in Silverlight 8.1. If you want to support background audio playback, you can continue to use a Windows Phone 8 app or create a Windows Phone Store app, which supports new background audio APIs.

So in this case you will have to write app that target WP8.0 Silverlight or or WP8.1 Store app.

The similar question was [here at MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c9275491-cfff-4078-bc6d-6debe5372790/backgroundaudioplayer-is-not-working-after-upgrading-windows-phone-8-apps-to-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: I have tried to implement BackgroundAudioPlayer Class in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight AudioPlaybackAgent project and tried calling its function in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. It doesn't shows any error but the app is unable to play the media file. Can you provide some suggestion on it.

Comment: @user3701667 The best would be if you had tried [the sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=219073). As for your code, many things might gone wrong - have you added refference to your AudioAgent project?

Comment: I have implemented this example only and have added the reference. I have used Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Audio Playback Agent project for implementing BackgroundAudioPlayer and using Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project for implementing its functions. Everything is being implemented as per the example but the app is unable to play the media file.

Comment: @user3701667 I'm not sure - have you tried to run the MSDN example? Have you tried to debug your program and see if AudioPlayer is receiving commands? Maybe there is a problem with aduio file not the Agent?

Comment: MSDN example is working fine for Windows Phone 8.0 but after implementing it in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 its not working. I have debugged the program the AudioPlayer class is not receiving any command. After the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play() command the app is unable to call AudioPlayer class.

Comment: @user3701667 Ups, sorry for little confusion, I've made a little research and it turns out that it won't work in Silverlight 8.1 (I also haven't managed to do that). More info in edited answer.

Comment: Okay...so Is there any way we can play media and collect sensors data both in background for Windows Phone 8.1??

Comment: @user3701667 Maybe you will be interested in [Responding to motion and orientation sensors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465294.aspx) and [Windows.Devices.Sensors namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.sensors.aspx) in Windows Store apps (Runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by Creating a new `Windows Runtime Component`. This is where your entry point for the Audio task will be. The entry point is a class that implements `IBackgroundTask`. This gives you one method that will be invoked on startup of the Audio task named Run.

In order to keep the Task alive indefinitely you need to keep track of the deferral that exists on the `IBackgroundTaskInstance`. Placing the deferral in a field for safe keeping will be enough. When the operating system cancels your task you will need to call Complete on this said deferral.

An example of a bare bone implementation of your task should look something like the following

```
public sealed class AudioPlayer : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;
    }
    private void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        _deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

for more Refrence you can go [here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/)

Comment: The basic idea of the app is I need to collect Motion sensor data in background and play a media file even if user is not in the app. If i implement AudioPlayer class in Windows Runtime Component how will I be able o collect sensors data in the background.